# JUnit5 BeforeAllCallback is executed for every test class

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I've the following classes:

```java
public class MyExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {
...
}

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class MyService1IT{
...
}

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class MyService2IT{
...
}
```

When executing the Tests with IntelliJ's `Run All Tests` or `mvn failsafe:integration-test` I can clearly see the `beforeAll` and `afterAll` method being executed for every class.
How can I avoid this? I though `ExtendWith` would only be executed once for these callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the ExtendWith mechanism only allows you to design reusable behavior, but the lifecycle is very similar to `@BeforeEach` / `@BeforeAll` methods.

But nothing stops you from implementing your own lifecycle in your extension.
Here's some code that will make sure it's only called once.

```
private static final AtomicBoolean FIRST_TIME = new AtomicBoolean(true);

// and in your method:

if(FIRST_TIME.getAndSet(false)){
    // code here that should only be run once
}
```

Note that this solution relies on being in the same VM / run. So if you have a fork mode per test or test class, you will need to use some external means of synchronization.

Comment: But https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/BeforeAllCallback.html states: „ additional behavior to test containers before all tests are invoked.“

Comment: I agree the wording sucks. But I think the important part here is "test containers". If I understand correctly, a class is a test container, which would make the statement correct.

Comment: Oh dear. I’m quite disappointed they don’t provide a unified way for that. Starting testcontainers for every integration test class is bad. Then I’ll go ahead and keep the state myself and Register a shutdown hook. Thanks

Comment: @Regyn I haven't tried this myself, but it looks like ExtensionContext may be what you want. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-keeping-state

Comment: I love that it again says "Usually, an extension is instantiated only once". Even the constructor is called multiple times. Anyway `extensionContext.getRoot().getStore()` seems to work indeed, so I can use that + BeforeAllCallback with AtomicBool. Thank you again!

Comment: Wow, why even call it BeforeAll. It's still a BeforeEach